# How to find beginning letters in string.I am getting errors in the program below

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void printfletter(char *);``
int main ()
{
    char a[50]="where are you";
    printfletter(a);
    return 0;
}
void printfletter(char *p)
{
    int i;
    printf("%c",*p);
    for (i=1;*(p+i)!='\0';i++)
    {
        if (*(p+i)==32)
        {
            printf("%c",*(++p));
        }   
    }
}
```

Program is to print all the beginning letters in string.
I should get the output as 'way'(w-where,a-are,y-you)
But i get 'whe'
I tried to implement it using functions and pointers.

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter (`p[i]`) is usually easier to both read and write.

Comment: What errors? Compile- or run-time? Please quote them. If it runs but has wrong behaviour, please explain what should happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Also please don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), If by the integer `32` you mean the ASCII code for space, please use an actual space instead, `' '`.

Comment: As for a *possible* hint about your problem, what do you think that `++p` does? Especially in combination with `p[i] != '\0'`. If you're not supposed to print spaces, then just check for *not* space and print normally in that case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks a lot for replying.I am kinda new to stack overflow.Its my first question.My program gives the wrong output.It does not have errors.

Comment: It does not have errors but gives a wrong output@underscore_d

Comment: For future question please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

First remove the last two characters in

```
void printfletter(char *);``
```

so it will compile. Then note that `*(++p)` will always choose the next character in the array. You really want the (i+1)th character, so replace your `printf` line with

```
        printf("%c",p[i+1]);
```

This will give you the output you want. I would recommend also making sure that you code does not exhibit undefined behaviour if you feed it the empty string.

Comment: `p[++i]` will lead to another problem when the loop iterates, as it will skip the next character.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a function similar to this:

```
// Argument is a constant pointer to constant character, because
// we neither modify the pointer nor modify the data it points to
void printfletter(const char * const p)
{
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        // The caller passed a null pointer
        return;  // Don't print anything, just return from the function
    }

    size_t i;  // Used as index into the string

    // First skip over all leading spaces, in case there is any
    for (i = 0; p[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        // If the current character is not a space, then break out of the loop
        if (!isspace(p[i]))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (p[i] == '\0')
    {
        // All of the string was space, no letters or anything else
        return;  // Don't print anything
    }

    // State variable, to say if the last character checked was a space
    bool last_was_space = true;  // Initialize to true, to print the first character

    // Iterate over all character in the null-terminated string
    // We reuse the index variable i, it will already be positioned at the
    // next character to check
    for (; p[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        // If the current character at index i is a space...
        if (isspace(p[i]))
        {
            // ... then set the state variable
            last_was_space = true;
        }
        // Otherwise, if the last character was a space...
        else if (last_was_space)
        {
            // ... then print the current character
            putchar(p[i]);

            // And reset the state
            last_was_space = false;
        }
        // Else do nothing
    }
}
```

The above function should print the first character of every space-delimited "word".

With the string you show (`"where are you"`) [it prints `way`](https://godbolt.org/z/a43W4v).